# How to get connection and Tableview work on single project? Xcode

Tags: mysql, objective-c, cocoa, xcode5, database-connection

Hello I'am new in Xcode and all kind of programming. I'am trying to compile several projects and methods to create a mac app that connects to MySql database ( not with php, i need it to be more secure) and get the data from the server to a table view with options to read,write and others. My problem for now is to get it connect and work with the object controller.
Here is what i have don so far:
**Can some One tell me where do I mistake?**

### DataRetrive .h

## import

## import

@interface DataRetrive : NSObject

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;

@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

- (IBAction)saveAction:(id)sender;

@end

### DataRetrive .m

These are the alerts than i get: *DataRetrive.m*
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxywUmCRt3i2aHRLSW9VWl9IV28/edit?usp=sharing

I have MySqlKitDatabase(h,m)
MySQLQuery(h,m)

And the frameworks and lib that i include
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxywUmCRt3i2QzFtRUxhT1pRblU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry, but StackExchange is **not** a *we-write-the-code-for-you* service..

Comment: I don't won't any one to rewrite my code just show me show me were do i mistake. Sorry if it seems I'am requesting for that kind a think. I guess i should of take my question some other way.

Comment: To format the code you should highlight it and tap "format code" button. And I can't see any code in DataRetrieve.m class. Can you edit the question?